# Why do I not have the 8px default margin on body?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, margin, default-value

When I set background-color, there are no white spaces as expected. My browser is chrome and it was a brand-new code, no other styles where applied in the CSS. Same thing happens with or without more components present in the HTML file. Added a div to try it out and same result.

```
body {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

Comment: provide a [mre] and take a look at [ask]

Comment: @nullptr I don't understand, is it always necessary to add code to questions? since it's a very simple background color on the body

Comment: just check the answer by Fran. it doesn't answer the question, and it could've been avoided if you just posted the code

Comment: You can even make your code run directly in StackOverflow with the `<>` button. It helps a lot.

Comment: @nullptr Sorry, is the first time I ask. Is it good now?

Comment: @nullptr the question initially asked doesn't really require any code. People answering the question don't know what is happening, that's all. Even with this code provided, they won't have the correct answer anyway.

Comment: @Peter Krebs I tried that and it says: Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code.

Comment: Thank you for your edit and comment  @Temani Afif

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, if you add any component or element inside , you would be offered a margin of 8px.

```html
<body>
    <div style="background-color:red;height: fit-content;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Gautam, 

Thanks for your reply. Added a div to try it out and got same result. No whitespace.

Comment: hey @Johanna sorry I missed _the white space_ part of the Question. In that case, you create a parent div and add a background to the element, which will produce the desired output.

Answer (score -2):

I would check the height and width of the component you are trying to see. Make sure neither of them are 0.

UPDATE: I think I understand your question better now. If you want to see the 8px margin on the body set by default in Chrome, run this code snippet.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.example {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class='example'/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is just the background color on the body, no other component

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question initially. If you are trying to see the 8px default margin set by the browser, try the code snippet I added to my answer in an update.

Answer (score -2):

Did you set both margin and padding to 0 in css?

You can style the body's margin to 8px if you would like to have the space without color or you can style the body's padding to 8px if you would like to get space color same as body background color.